# Rateit plugin doesn't preset double value from View Model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, rating

I don't know whats going on. I'm using [RateIt Plugin](http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm)
for my web Application. The problem is that `data-rateit-vaue` doesn't work properly. Specify the plugin doesn't preset value if my value contains decimal places. If no everything ok. Also it can set the value with decimal places from the script `$('#' + photoId).rateit('value', result.averageRating);` and it work's fine. What's wrong with my code in View?

`Average Raiting <span class="rateit" id="@Model.PhotoId" data-rateit-readonly="true" data-rateit-ispreset="true" data-rateit-value="@Model.AverageRating"></span>`

P.S. If I change my code in view like `data-rateit-value="1.12324 ... 324"` everything works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my problem. I just need to specify the Invariant culture to get a period as decimal separator:
`data-rateit-value="@Model.AverageRating.ToString("0.00000", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)"`